# How does PMF change given that you know p?

Tags: statistics

For example this question:

A biased coin lands heads with probability $\frac{2}{3}$. The coin is tossed three times.

a) Given that there was at least one head in the three tosses, what is the probability that there were at least two heads?

Normally without the `There was at least one head in the three tosses` the PMF using binomial distribution would be:

$$
\begin{equation*}
p(0) = \binom{3}{0}*\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^0*\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3\\
p(1) = \binom{3}{1}*\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^1*\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2\\
p(2) = \binom{3}{2}*\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2*\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^1\\
p(3) = \binom{3}{3}*\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3*\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^0
\end{equation*}
$$

However since we know there is at least one head, the $p(0)$ shouldn't exist anymore, right?. But the PMF should add up to one. What happens to $p(0)$? Does it get distributed evenly along the rest of the $p(x)$?

Comment: Good question. There is a whole bunch of machinery for dealing with this sort of problem, including the notion of *conditional probability* of event $A$ *given* event $B$, notation $\Pr(A\mid B)$. The definition, if $\Pr(B)\ne 0$, is $\Pr(A\mid B)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$.  In your case, $B$ is the event at least one head, and $A$ the event at least two heads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We renormalize by taking the only possible outcomes. So the renormalization factor in your (good) notation is

$$\frac{1}{p(1) + p(2) + p(3)}$$

Hence the probability you want is

$$\frac{p(2) + p(3)}{p(1) + p(2) + p(3)}$$

Comment: That's so cool to me. Awesome, thanks this answered my question.